# categorized style in 2.14 returns faulty values

Tags: qgis, style

i have just tested latest release of qgis with a simple dataset. it is polygon data - type geodatabase with some categorial columns. the one i've tested characterises land-use types in 15 categories. colum-type is integer - value range is from 1 to 15.
layer properties / style / categorized / classify returns the following classification:
[image]

these values originate from the first numeric column within the corresponding attribute table - instead of the selected column.

are there any known workarounds yet ?

Comment: Cannot duplicate your issue on a postgis table. The selected column (and no other column) is used for classification?

Comment: Can you maybe post your attribute table?

Comment: tried to reproduce with a shape-file copy of my gdb-dataset. classification worked fine with that shp !  according to my additional tests this seems to be gdb-related, becuase graduated style returns faulty classification too. has anyone tested gdbs right now and similar results ? ... i can send a section of the data including geometry (dbd)

Comment: ... maybe a bug tracker issue ?? right now i am trying to find an interim-workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it's a bug in the GDAL geodatabase driver. Can you file it over at http://hub.qgis.org/issues along with a copy of your dataset and I'll follow it up with the GDAL crew?

Comment: just added a bug-report to hub.qgis.org

Answer (score 1):

finally found a **solution** (i.e. a **workaround**) for (ESRI)geodatabases:

(.. which potentially doesn't support the GDAL-driver hypothesis (?))

uese expressions !
instead of selecting a field form the properties/style/categorized/column-dropdown i use the following expression: "lbtyp" * 1
where "lbtyp" is my categorial field 

**the resulting classification works fine.**

the same procedure works with graduated-type as well !
[image]

Comment: Good workaround! There's still a bug in gdal itself though (QGIS falls back to a slower, non GDAL categorization when an expression is used)

Comment: your comment draws my attention back on one of my questions from last year (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/95166/query-filter-on-attribute-tables-with-external-tables-joined) ... where i argued that not beeing able to have selects on objects from joined tables is like having databasesystems without SELECT on VIEWS and use CREATE TABLE instead ... which would be a no-go there. ... are those two things somehow related in GDAL ?